# Set start screen and desktop wallpaper in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime

In WinRT you can set the lock screen image using:

```
LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file);
```

Is there a way to also set the start screen image and desktop wallpaper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows Store apps do not have access to set the start screen image or desktop wallpaper.